# Why do Roblox textboxes always give a nil result?

Tags: lua, roblox

My problem is that I'm trying to get a custom input from the user in the form of TextBoxes. More specifically, I want to give players a chance to input feedback about my Roblox Game but the text from the textbox keeps being nil even when I type something into it. I expect it's probably an error on my part but I'm a tad unsure.

So currently, it looks like this on the client:

```
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.Visible = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Feedback.Text = ""
    wait(.1)
    local success,nilmessage,Error = game.ReplicatedStorage.Feedback.SendFeedback:InvokeServer(script.Parent.Parent.Feedback.Text) --Invoking the server part.
    print ("Message RAW = "..script.Parent.Parent.Feedback.Text)--Checking the text
    --There's more stuff after here but this is the main part.
    
    
end)
```

The print statement always prints: `Message Raw =`  and the server receives a nil value.

Any advice would be appreciated, if you need more, let me know.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: share the server part. this script looks ok

Comment: That print statement always prints nothing, so how could it be the script if it is nil before even reaching the server?

Comment: you said it prints "Message Raw = ". now you say it prints nothing. what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as you say the print statement always prints `Message RAW = "`:

Here you assign an emtpy string:

```
script.Parent.Parent.Feedback.Text = ""
```

and here you concatenate and print it:

```
 print ("Message RAW = "..script.Parent.Parent.Feedback.Text)
```

So the print that you observe is what is to be expected.

Why your server receives a nil value I cannot tell because you refuse to share the code on request.